# Licence for including (with HTML embed tag) others YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

Do I need any Licence for including (with HTML embed tag) others YouTube videos in my website?
I just want to show some cool YouTube videos in my website, but those videos aren't neither created by me nor by my friends. I don't want to add any download link; just to include the videos

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about video production, but rather a question about law and websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the YouTube embed feature then it is allowed according to the YouTube terms of service. If the uploader doesn't want their video to be embedded they can simply turn it off in the video manager.

What is not allowed, whether the embed feature is enabled or not, is that you rip the video from YouTube and then distribute it from your own servers. The only exception is that the video author gave you permission to do this.

Also, you may get a cease and desist letter if you have a habit of just putting a ton of YouTube videos on your webpages and some ads and no original content of your own.

Comment: Do I need the author's permission, for Uploading the video to my web server?

Comment: @user Yes. As a general rule of thumb, you are not allowed to save other people's content unless they give you permission. Since it is on youtube, as a user of the youtube site you submit yourself to the YouTube terms of service which are that you will not download videos from youtube and upload them somewhere else.

Comment: In practicality, this really only matters on videos that make money from ads. Videos of your mom's cat probably don't count.

Comment: If the author gave me the permission for Uploading the video into my website, do I have to upload any files (like permission.txt/license.txt/the author's E-sign or something like that) in my server?

Comment: @user Not legally, but it's a good idea to get things in writing.

Comment: Except there's creative commons and gnu licenses that do require such a thing. Those are generic licenses that authors can just publicize that their content falls under.

Comment: Do I need any Licence for just downloading a video from YouTube, with vidmate Android app?

Comment: Is it legal, to download YouTube videos with vidmate?

Comment: @user Technically against YouTube terms of service, which can bring legal action theoretically, but I've never heard of that happening. If you have the creator's permission it doesn't really make a difference. It all comes down to acquiring the creator's permission.

Comment: If it's available on the videos you want, just use the YouTube embed feature. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player You don't need permission if it's available.